# How to define constant in PHP

Tags: php

I do not understand how this code work.
displaying code below , in this code i defined a constant and the value is 10 but it display the output "constant is not defined".

why?

```
define('HELLO', 10);        
if(defined(HELLO))        
{        
    echo "Constant is defined";        
}        
else        
{        
    echo "Constant is not defined";        
}        

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change:

```
defined(HELLO)
```

to:

```
defined('HELLO')
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php

Answer (score 0):

Define Constant in PHP:

```
define("HELLO", 10);
```

If condition needs to change, then: `defined("HELLO")`

Answer (score -1):

Even you can follow this way of checking and defining constant in PHP.

```
defined('CONSTANT') or define('CONSTANT', 'SomeDefaultValue');
```

For your question, you have made a mistake of `quote`. follow as :

```
if(defined('HELLO')){
  echo "Constant is already defined";
}else{
  echo "Constant is not defined, you can define it.";
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php#84439

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question why it didn't work in the first place.